# JSF - How to change the input type depending on list size

Tags: jsf

I am a newbie to JSF and I am trying to show a dropdown if a `List` has more than 1 element.  If it is a `List` with a single element I want to display an `outputText`.  Here is my `xhtml`

```
<lp:repeat value="#{addBean.donation.instruments.checks}" var="check">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <ui:fragment rendered="#{addBean.checkTypes.size == 1}">
        <h:selectOneMenu value="#{check.checkType}">
          <f:selectItems value="#{addBean.checkTypes}"/>
        </h:selectOneMenu>
      </ui:fragment>
      <ui:fragment rendered="#{addBean.checkTypes.size > 1}">
        <h:outputText value="#{addBean.checkTypes.get(0).label}"></h:outputText>                  
      </ui:fragment>
    </td>
  </tr>
</lp:repeat>
```

`checkTypes` is a `List` of `SelectItem`.  I see the dropdown being populated by the `checkTypes` and when one is selected it is pushed into the `check` variable that is declared at the top.  When the `List` has only one element, the `label` is displayed in an `outputText`.  When that happens I cannot figure out how to bind that value into the `check` variable.  Could someone please point me in the right direction?  Or is there a better way to implement this pattern?

Answer (score 0):

you can use the twoo componentes with no problem using the attribute rendered.

The rendered is used to 'show' your componente or not based in some logical conditions (true or false)

Use something like this:

```
 <h:selectOneMenu value="#{check.checkType}" rendered="#{addBean.checkTypes.size > 1}">
       <f:selectItems value="#{addBean.checkTypes}"/>
    </h:selectOneMenu>


<h:outputLabel value="value="#{addBean.checkTypes[0]}"" rendered="#{addBean.checkTypes.size == 1}"/>
```

Comment: The result of this needs to be pushed into `check.checkType` and the `outputLabel` does not do that, it just renders it to the page.